# Get-AzureADPolicy : The term 'Get-AzureADPolicy' is not recognized

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

After connecting to Azure AD with **Connect-AzureAD** , If run the command **Get-AzureADPolicy**, PowerShell is prompting the message as "Get-AzureADPolicy : The term 'Get-AzureADPolicy' is not recognized"

Answer (score 13):

1. First **Disconnect-AzureAD** from the logged-in session
2. Second **UnInstall-Module AzureAD**
3. Third **Install-Module AzureADPreview**
4. Forth **connect-AzureAD**
   Then try **Get-AzureADPolicy**

This will work

Comment: It's a mystery why the general availability version doesn't include the command that has been in preview for the same release version and is included in the documentation for the release version.

Comment: when i tried to uninstall it told me azureAD was in use. I just closed and reopened powershell (as admin) and then uninstall worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
Install-Module AzureADPreview
```

failed to install at first. Then I have installed `AzureAD`:

```
Install-Module AzureAD
```

The `Get-AzureADPolicy` was still missing, so I tried to install `AzureADPreview` again (without removing `AzureAD`).

```
Install-Module AzureADPreview
```

This time it proceeded where it has failed previously. Adding the `-AllowClobber` argument fixed the installation problem.

```
Install-Module AzureADPreview -AllowClobber
```

Restarted Powershell and `Get-AzureADPolicy` worked.

Answer (score 0):

for some reason after installing the module didn't import automatically. After the import-module AzureADPreview it worked for me